# Какой подход выбрать в css?

Tags: css, вёрстка, jsx

У меня есть в jsx-файле элементы, которые мне необходимо стилизовать в css. Вопрос: мне нужно сразу в css объявить эти элементы, задать им размеры и позиции на своем мониторе и только потом приступать к медиа-адаптации или сразу писать медиа-адаптацию, пропуская первый шаг?

Comment: Как вам удобно.